# Images Not precompiled in Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

On rebooting my rails app in development, I am getting the error:

Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled

```
<%= image_tag "logo.png" %>
```

If I comment out the image, the next image asset throws the same error.  The images are in the assets/images directory.

The app worked fine before I rebooted and I didnt make any config, code or environment changes in between.

What does the error mean in the development context?  What could cause it to suddenly stop working?

Comment: Did you do a `rake assets:precompile` in development? Because that sometimes messes things up. Are you also using webpacker?

Comment: I'm using webpacker, but I didn't do rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 0):

Check the `config/environments/development.rb` file and update the `config.assets.debug` setting-

`config.assets.debug = true (if TRUE change it to FALSE)`

Comment: this does not fix it.  also, it was set to true when it previously worked